# Search and display both lowercase() and uppercase() results

Tags: jquery

I am trying to search for rows in my table and the table displays results based on the search word, the jQuery does the job but if you search for say "Hello" but with a lowercase "h" it doesn't show that row. I want it to ignore the lowercase and uppercase thing, Was wondering if someone could guide how I could make it do that?

```
$('#search').keyup(function () {
            var data = this.value.split(" ");
            var rows = $(".Info tbody tr").hide();
            if(this.value ==""){
                rows.show();
                return;
            }
            rows.hide();
            rows.filter(function(i,v){
                var t = $(this);
                for (var d = 0; d < data.length; d++) {
                    if (t.is(":Contains('" + data[d] + "')")) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }).show();
        });

<table style ="width:95%" class = "patientInfo">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Select </th>
                        <th>Patient Name</th>
                        <th>Hospital Number</th>
                        <th>Date of Birth</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                </table>
```

The user manually enters the rows therefore I only wrote HTML for the headings.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- Making a copy of the data in your filter function, and make that text lowercase
- Do the filter based on the lowercase text

Comment: I tried doing var t = $(this).text().toLowerCase(); It didn't work, is that what you mean?

Comment: Try to copy and lowercase data[d], as well. If your text is lowercase but you're still searching for 'Apple' you're out of luck.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am still confused, what do you mean lowercase data[d]